# Problem with Gallio and TeamCity and the new Visual Studio 2010 release

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.0, teamcity

I am running TeamCity on a virtual machine. I have installed the new Visual Studio 2010 release yesterday and converted my VS 2008 projects. I also have installed .NET Framework 4 on my virtual machine.

Before yesterday all my projects were building succesfully on the CI server but since I installed VS 2010 I get the following error message :

error MSB5014: File format version is not recognized.  MSBuild can only read solution files between versions 7.0 and 9.0, inclusive.

I did change my config on Team City to take into account the new .NET 4 framework :

Build Runner : MSBuild

Build File Path : CFT.msbuild

MSBuild version : Microsoft.NET Framework 4.0

MSBuild ToolsVersion : 4.0

Run Platform : x86

I think it has something to do with the fact that now MSBuild must refer to .NET 4 framwork but it seems that it keeps refering to 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5256515